# Is there a native JAI implementation for Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit? I'm trying to boost geoserver performance

Tags: geoserver, java, ubuntu, jai

Is there a native JAI implementation for Ubuntu 14.04  64 bit? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Such does not exist and you should be able to get more boost with Marlin renderer http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/jmeter/jmeter_marlin.html. But before the boost from JAI or Marlin becomes meaningful you must have done the basics right with imagery and vector sources.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for your response. I may not have done the basics. Can you refer me to what they are?

Comment: If you follow this you should be on the right way http://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-on-steroids-foss4g-2015.